# RadioButtons Highlighting Incorrectly

Tags: vb.net

On my form, I have 4 RadioButtons, each with its appearance set to `Button`. In my program, I change each of these RadioButton's `ForeColour`, `BackColour` and `AutoCheck` status, as below:

```
ARadioButton.AutoCheck = False
ARadioButton.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ControlLightLight)
ARadioButton.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ControlDark)
```

However, later on, I reset these properties back to default:

```
ARadioButton.AutoCheck = True
ARadioButton.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
ARadioButton.ForeColor = DefaultForeColor
```

My issue is that instead of the entire button being highlighted, only the outside is, as shown in the images below.

Originally:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvd5x.png]

After changes are made and RadioButtons reset to default using code above:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ9hG.png]

I know this may seem trivial, but I would like the entire `RadioButton` to be highlighted when the user clicks on the `RadioButton`, not just the outside.

Is there a way I could somehow reset this?

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't put the pictures directly in the post. I don't have enough reputation. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the BackColor property to Color.Transparent